# Two $this->request->data. How to multiply them together?

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I multiply

```
$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose']
*
$this->request->data['Unit']['conversion']
```

I am trying to store my unit dose values relatively, so in my Units table I have a conversion field which is a number relative to the unit. I get the 'dose' from a form. And this function is inside my controllers 'add' function for that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values will be strings, so first convert the values to numeric data types, then use the multiplication operator (`*`).

Assuming your values are integers, you can do

```
$product = (int)$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] * (int)$this->request->data['Unit']['conversion'];
```

Substitute `(int)` for the [type conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php) that is appropriate in your situation.